# Pandas Dataframe - How to get a Rolling Sum grouped by a value?

Tags: python, pandas

Working with some COVID-19 data, how should I be calculating a 14 day rolling sum of case counts?

Here's my existing code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv'
all_counties = pd.read_csv(url, dtype={"fips": str})
all_counties.date = pd.to_datetime(all_counties.date)
oregon = all_counties.loc[all_counties['state'] == 'Oregon']

oregon.set_index('date', inplace=True)
oregon['delta']=oregon.groupby(['state','county'])['cases'].diff().fillna(0)
oregon.head()
```

This code calculates the daily incremental case count (thanks to an earlier question's answers).

The next step is calculating the rolling 14 day sum, for which I have attempted this:

```
oregon['rolling_14']=oregon.groupby(['state','county'])['delta'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=14).sum()
```

It is unfortunately failing.  If I have a single county's data, this works:

```
county['rolling_14']=county.rolling(min_periods=1, window=14).sum()
```

But unfortunately, this isn't viable when the data frame contains multiple counties' datasets.

Answer (score 1):

The `groupby().rolling()` has two extra index level, namely `state, county`. Remove them and assignment would work

```
oregon['rolling_14'] = (oregon.groupby(['state','county'])['delta']
                            .rolling(min_periods=1, window=14).sum()
                            .reset_index(level=['state','county'])
                       )
```

Also, since you are working with several groupby functions, lazy groupby would help improve run time/code base a bit:

```
groups = oregon.groupby(['state','county'])
oregon['delta'] = groups['cases'].diff().fillna(0)

oregon['rolling_14'] = (groups['delta']
                            .rolling(min_periods=1, window=14).sum()
                            .reset_index(level=['state','county'])
                       )
```